# Swift StoryBoard Auto Layout

Tags: swift, autolayout, storyboard

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NB4Sc.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pnor0.png)

I've been trying to work with Swift Auto Layout all day, but it's not going as planned, so I'm asking for help. I'm trying to accomplish two things as follows:

Regardless of the device's resolution and ratio, as shown in the image above, I want to position three buttons with appropriate spacing at the bottom 3/4 of the screen.

I want the width and height of the three UIButtons to be set to the size of their respective images.

For the first task, no matter what method I try with SafeArea and SuperView, it's not working as I want. For the second task, I can't find a way to set the values in the inspector.

Comment: Your goal is not very well defined. You say "bottom 3/4 of the screen" but *which point* exactly should be at the bottom 3/4 of the screen? The image you showed looks like the buttons start at a little bit over half of the screen. Also, since you fixed the buttons' width and height, what if there is not enough space in the bottom 3/4 of the screen to show all the buttons?